# Pull matching names with one word from text files

Tags: regex, grep

I have a list of many users and I would like to only match the ones with one word in them

```
**txt1.txt**
charles
first
charles users
user sample
sample

**txt2.txt**
mike
charles users
charles
welcome
first
```

I am using grep to find matches in the files

```
grep -xF -f txt1.txt txt2.txt
```

What would I have to add or use in order to match only words with one letter?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: charles and first, they are the single letter words that are in both files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier with awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $0 in a' txt1.txt txt2.txt
charles
first
```

- Creation of array is done using `a[$1]` to ensure only first word is used in array
- `$0 in a` is done to make sure complete string from file2 matches that of file1

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, you can do this with

```
join <(awk NF==1 txt1.txt | sort -u) <(awk NF==1 txt2.txt | sort -u)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
awk NF==1 txt1.txt txt2.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==2{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

i think hek2mgl answer matches all words, but not the lines with one word. Heres the line version:

```
grep -o '^[^\s]+$' file1 file2 ...
```